# Is it possible to run commands before running tasks in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, nvm, vscode-tasks

I want to run 'nvm use' command before running one task in NPM Scripts. And I try to use vsc-nvm plugin, as it runs 'nvm use' before task is run, but not work.

So may I know whether there is one other way to run commands before running tasks in VSCode?

Comment: If you configure your own "shell" type task, you can set a custom script as the "command" to execute when running it, then you can add whatever actual commands you want, just by modifying the script.

Comment: Yes. I know it. but I want to use one official function called "NPM SCRIPTS" in EXPLORER to kick start some scripts set in package.json. And this NPM SCRIPTS function will automatically call script as a task that I CAN NOT config anything.